# How to access class method inside an anonymous function

Tags: javascript

I have an method in my JS class and in the callback of a Promise, I want it to call another class method.

```
class MyClass {
   myClassMethod(arg1) {
         // this method did get called
   }
   
   aSecondClassMethod() {
          //...
   }

   methodWithPromise() {
       var myClassMethod = this.myClassMethod;
       let aPromise = methodReturnPromise(); 
       aPromise.then(function (value) {
           myClassMethod(value);
   }
 }
```

So I create a var calls `myClassMethod` and set that to `this.myClassMethod`.
And when I debug the code, myClassMethod did get called in the `then` callback of the Promise.

The problem I am having is when my `myClassMethod()` calls other class method(),  i.e.

```
myClassMethod(args) {
  aSecondClassMethod();
}
```

I get error saying `aSecondClassMethod` is undefined.  I tried

```
myClassMethod(args) {
  this.aSecondClassMethod();
}
```

But it gives me the same error.  I think I can work around this by declaring a var for each of the class method that myClassMethod() calls.

```
   var aSecondClassMethod= this.aSecondClassMethod;
```

But that seem cumbersome to maintain the code going forward.

I would like to know if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: [arrow function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an arrow function, as it captures the `this` value of the enclosing context.

```
aPromise.then(value => this.myClassMethod(value));
```

Comment: Probably a good idea to include an explanation as to why the arrow function works and a regular function does not.

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend using the new `() => {}` function notation for defining the class method that contains the promise. Without that (or an old school bind) `this` will still be `undefined`.

My usual style:

```
class MyClass {

  myClassMethod = (value) => {
    //something..
  };

  methodWithPromise = () => {
    somePromise
      .then((res) => {
        this.myClassMethod(res);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
        return;
      });
  };
}
```